# Updating Firebase object with data passed from child to parent in react JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, components

I am passing input data onSubmit from a child component to a parent component in react JS. This input data is then appended to an object in a database with the corresponding id(key). Upon submitting the data and pushing it to the database, only the first letter of the text I input is ever pushed. Why is this?

CHILD COMPONENT

```
<input type="text" className="Question-Answer" id={props.id} name="Answer" placeholder="Your Answer..." onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event.target.value,props.id)}></input>
```

PARENT COMPONENT

```
postAnswerHandler = ( answer,id ) => {
        
        console.log('This was clicked!'+id)
        
        axios.get( 'https://blog-6d4da-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/posts/'+id+'.json' )
        
            .then( response => {
                let newAnswer = answer;
                let response_1 = JSON.stringify(response.data);
                
                const newData = {
                    answer: newAnswer,...response.data
                };

                axios.put('/posts/'+id+'.json', newData);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used axios.patch() instead of axios.put() and this solved the issue for me.